# PHP - How to get session current shipping method title

Tags: checkout, shipping-methods, session

This is code i use for getting current session shipping method code:

```
<?PHP echo Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod(); ?>
```

But this code is only giving me the current session shipping method code not the shipping title.

How can i get the current session shipping method title ?

Comment: This is close to what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032936/how-do-i-get-the-shipping-method-the-user-has-chosen-during-checkout

Comment: Can you post the exact code that you think i must use as your answer to this question ?

Comment: <?php echo Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getShippingDescription(); ?>

Comment: not working....

Answer (score 2):

If the shipping method is estimated on the cart page or checkout page, you should be able to get the title of the shipping method with:

`Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getShippingDescription();`

Please keep in mind that this will return an empty string if it wasn't chosen on the cart page or checkout.

I added the title on top of the cart. in 
`app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml`

`echo "<pre>" . Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getShippingDescription() . "</pre><br />";`

[image]